# Issue with loading Sage on Cantor

Tags: 14.04, kde, sagemath

Programs in use:

- Sage 8.1
- Cantor 0.5 using KDE Dev Platform 4.13.3
- Cantor-backend-sage 4.13.30ubuntu0.1

I had no problems with Sage attaching to Cantor. The problem is Cantor can't seem to load Sage. The program is stuck in an initializing session.

Comment: Nothing for us to answer here. We need errors, a log status or something that gives any sort of notice about an issue.  "stuck" is too generic.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no error that pops up.

Answer (score 1):

For me this solution seems to be working:

1. install Cantor as you already done with

   ```
   sudo apt-get install cantor cantor-backend-sage
   ```
2. install SageMath *7.5.1~aimsppa5*  from [their PPA](https://launchpad.net/~aims/+archive/ubuntu/sagemath?field.series_filter=trusty):

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:aims/sagemath
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install sagemath-upstream-binary-full
   ```
3. launch Cantor and select SageMath backend at start

I tested this approach on my Kubuntu 14.04.5 amd64 VM. I got the following results.

In terminal:

```
$ cantor 
Bus::open: Can not get ibus-daemon's address. 
IBusInputContext::createInputContext: no connection to ibus-daemon 
Object::disconnect: Unexpected null parameter
cantor(3022)/kdeui (kdelibs): Attempt to use QAction "" with KXMLGUIFactory!
```

after installaftion of "missed" `ibus` package it shows:

```
$ cantor 
Object::disconnect: Unexpected null parameter
cantor(2285)/kdeui (kdelibs): Attempt to use QAction "" with KXMLGUIFactory!
```

and in GUI:

[image: Cantor initializes Sage]

So it does not start on my system.

I reported [bug 1743774 to LaunchPad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cantor/+bug/1743774).

Comment: I installed the latest version of Sage which is 8.1. Could this be a compatibility issue with KDE? If, so should I then try using 7.5.1 since it is in a repository?

Comment: Plus I am unable to add the repository. I get this error. 'Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:aims/sagemath'. Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.

Comment: It is strange. You tagged question with 14.04 tag, I have added this PPA to my 14.04 experimental VM. Which Ubuntu version do you have?

Comment: Kernal: 4.40-109-generic, Distribution: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS 64bit

Comment: Could it be that I am using Ubuntu Gnome?

Comment: I'll try to install on my 14.04 KDE VM and report back.

Comment: It does not work on my system, so I reported bug.

Comment: Thanks. I though I was doing something wrong.